# Having trouble timing turtle movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timer, turtle-graphics

I wrote the following code, which creates expanding squares at two random locations.  I would like to write a function **f(squares, seconds)** so that if the user inputs f(5,10), a new square would begin forming every 10 seconds, until 5 had formed.

I can't seem to find anything which lets me start a new square while one is still forming.  I can either make two form at the same time, as in the code below, or have one be completed, and then for another to start forming.  Help?

```
import sys
sys.setExecutionLimit(1000000)
import turtle
import random
wn = turtle.Screen()
#Creates alex the turtle
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.color('blue')
alex.pensize(3)
alex.ht()
alex.penup()
#creates bob the turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.color('blue')
bob.pensize(3)
bob.ht()
bob.penup()

#Sets variables so that alex starts in a random location
a=random.randrange(360)
b=random.randrange(360)
x=random.randrange(50,150)
y=random.randrange(50,150)
#Sets variables so that bob starts in a random location
l=random.randrange(360)
m=random.randrange(360)
n=random.randrange(50,150)
o=random.randrange(50,150)
#Moves alex to his random starting location
alex.speed(100)
alex.left(a)
alex.forward(x)
alex.left(b)
alex.forward(y)
alex.pendown()
#Moves bob to his random starting location
bob.speed(100)
bob.left(l)
bob.forward(n)
bob.left(m)
bob.forward(o)
bob.pendown()

#Draws the 2 squares
for i in range(1,500):
    alex.forward(i)
    alex.left(90)
    bob.forward(i)
    bob.left(90)
```

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you want requires independent execution threads.  You need to work with the multi-threading [package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

You will want logic such as this:

```
import time
import threading

def draw_square():
    # Draw a square in a random place
    length = random.randrange(360)
    width  = random.randrange(360)
    x_pos  = random.randrange(50,150)
    y_pos  = random.randrange(50,150)

    # Continue with your square-drawing logic;
    # you already know how to do this.

while True:
    threading.thread(draw_square)
    time.sleep(10)
```